# Strange result from SQLite query using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I have a table in my DB. In that table, I have a value stored (it's a date, in milliseconds): "1424386800000", in a column named "fechainicio".

I have downloaded SQLite browser in my Mac to actually check that the value is stored, and its correct, and it is.

Later, in my code, I retrieve that value using this:

```
var fechaInicio:Int64=Int64(results!.intForColumn("fechainicio"))
```

When I do this, I am receiving the value "-1542342272".

Why is the value retrieved incorrectly?

I have tried also

```
var fechaInicio:Int64=results!.intForColumn("fechainicio").toIntMax()
```

and

```
var fechaInicio=results!.intForColumn("fechainicio")
```

Isn't Int64 the correct type to retrieve a long value from a database?

Comment: You need to fetch using stringForColumn and then typecast this to double. This is not strange result. IntForColumn gives 10 digit value.

Comment: Well, there is no long type in Swift. As far as I know, the Long type in Swift is... Int64

Comment: The `int` type from (Objective-)C is `Int32` in Swift. Truncating 1424386800000 to 32-bit gives -1542342272. You should use `longForColumn()` (assuming that this is FMDB).

Comment: That makes more sense to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `int` type from (Objective-)C is a 32-bit integer type (and mapped to `Int32` in Swift). This means that the

```
- (int)intForColumn:(NSString*)columnName;
```

method from FMDB can return only 32-but values. This method ultimately calls the SQLite function

```
int sqlite3_column_int(sqlite3_stmt*, int iCol);
```

which returns the lower 32-bit of the value, without any overflow check.
The proper solution is to use

```
- (long)longForColumn:(NSString*)columnName;
```

instead which returns `Int64` in Swift.

Comment: Great and detailed explanation. Thank you for not only giving the solution, but also WHY was failing.